# Where can I find the required parameters for different cards when accepting payments online

Tags: php, paypal, payment, credit-card

I am building a shopping cart and I am using PayPal Payments Pro to handle my payments.

I am accepting American Express, Discover, Visa, MasterCard and Maestro (including Switch) cards. Does anybody know what PayPal needs for each of these cards? I know that some cards don't require a start date when making payments online, and some cards also contain issue numbers.

I want to know what each card requires so that I can ask for the relevant information on my HTML form and validate everything on the server end.

Thanks,

Peter

Comment: Doesn't PayPal handle everything for your? I would be vary wary of collecting any credit/bank card data at all. If you leave it all to PayPal so the data never comes near you, you're pretty safe from any accusation about mishandiling data, and nobody can steal the data from you.

Comment: PayPal will handle the payment however I am taking the credit card details from my website, and sending it to paypal (via cURL) using their API

Comment: OK. I guess I was really talking as an individual rather than a proper business. Collecting data like that would scare the life out of me. Serious security implications.

Comment: I wouldn't be storing the data, just handling it as the customer enters it, and sending it directly to PayPal

Comment: Yeah but you have to get the SSL right, and more. And people have to trust you're not doing anything with the data. I really thought to use paypal you didn't have to take any data yourself.

Comment: Nic, read up on PayPal Payments Pro and PayPal Payments Standard. I will implement both. The difference is one option processes the payments from my website, the other option from paypals website. I have a 256-bit SSL certificate and as I said, the customers card details won't be stored.

Answer (score 1):

Maestro/Switch are the only cards that require a start date or issue number.

Visa, MasterCard, Amex, and Discover only require the cc number and expiration date, and then depending on your PayPal config all cards may or may not require a valid billing address and/or card security code.